# How to create an sysimage of Julia through PyJulia with a specific library?

Tags: python, julia

The `python3 -m julia.sysimage sys_py.so` builds the image.

But when applying this image to the file, I do not observe any acceleration. Most likely this is due to the fact that my library is not in the image. How to fix it?

For example my main Julia file `main.jl`.

```
using DifferentialEquations

a = solve(
    ODEProblem((x, p, t) -> 4.0, 1.0, (0.50 - 0.50, 0.50)),
    BS3(),
    abstol = 1e-8,
)(
    0.50,
)
println(a)
```

Which performs by the `julia main.jl` in 12.5 s.

I create an image for him with the help of Julia herself:

```
using PackageCompiler
create_sysimage(
    ["DifferentialEquations"],
    sysimage_path = "sysimage.so",
    precompile_execution_file = "main.jl",
)
```

In this case, execution through the `julia --sysimage sysimage.so` command occurs in 1.5 s. That is, the image works.

If I write in PyJulia and run it, then it performs all the same 12.5 s.

```
from julia import Main as jl


jl.eval("using DifferentialEquations")

result = jl.eval("""
    a = solve(
        ODEProblem((x, p, t) -> 4.0, 1.0, (0.50 - 0.50, 0.50)),
        BS3(),
        abstol = 1e-8,
        )(
        0.50,
    )
    """
)
print(result)
```

If I generate an image with a PyJulia with the help of the `python3 -m julia.sysimage sys.so` command, then all this is torn and does not help. The code is executed in 12.5 s. My code:

```
from julia.api import LibJulia

api = LibJulia.load()
api.sysimage = "sys_py.so"
api.init_julia()

from julia import Main as jl


jl.eval("using DifferentialEquations")

result = jl.eval("""
    a = solve(
        ODEProblem((x, p, t) -> 4.0, 1.0, (0.50 - 0.50, 0.50)),
        BS3(),
        abstol = 1e-8,
        )(
        0.50,
    )
    """
)
print(result)
```

I want to quickly import the DifferentialEquations library. How can I achieve this with PyJulia?

Comment: The phrase "all this is torn" seems to be a typo. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: This is not a real answer, but it does look like when you run the sysimage using Julia that you are specifying the sysimage. On the other hand, when you run via Python, you aren't specifying the sysimage. It would make complete sense that the reason that you aren't getting the speedup is simply that you aren't using the image.

Comment: No. I add. See the last listing.

Comment: I see that now.

I am wondering if that is actually having an effect. It might be interesting to trace to see if it is actually reading the system image. If so, it might be that the julia you get is a different one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to start PyJulya.

But I found an interesting JuliaCall library.

It has not yet implemented the connection of the system image, but this is not a big deal.

I replaced the system image generated by the PackageCompiler with the default one by simple copying.

I use docker, so I don't have to worry about the system Julia changing.
In this case, the python library works great.

However, do not put pythoncall libraries in this image.

Suddenly it will help someone.